# PFsense not routing from wan to ipv6 lease

Tags: routing, ipv6, pfsense

I have a pfsense router connected to starlink internet. It's currently providing me a /56 that I'm using to provide IPV6 leases via the DHCPv6 server. I have serval devices that have active IPV6 address provided to them, windows 10 desktop, Raspberry Pi, NAS. I can ping ipv6.google.com from all of them.

Now onto my problem. I cannot ping my windows 10 desktop from the Wan interface on the PFsense router or from the internet. I can ping the other two devices from both the wan interface and the internet. I can also successfully ping the desktop from the Lan interface on the router, and other devices on the lan.

I have tried releasing and renewing the lease. The lease for the desktop shows up in pfsense lease list so it's aware of it.

I looked at the firewall rules and there is nothing specific to that address to that appears to block ipv6 traffic (which makes sense considering the other devices work).

I have not tried a static route yet.

Comment: Does the traffic _arrive at_ the WAN interface? If you ping a local host from the internet, does that show up in `tcpdump -e -n -i em0` or such?

Comment: @user1686 The tcpdump command never returned from the command prompt, but I did a packet capture while I was pinging (not much ipv6 traffic) and it got a ping request to the lan IPv6 address.

Comment: For anyone who finds this later the solution is that windows by default with windows firewall on blocks echo requests not from the same subnet. So that's why it was not working [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1543625/which-windows-firewall-rule-blocks-ping-icmp-on-the-ipv6-side) super user article explains and has the solution.